# How to crop background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to crop background image with custom form.. but I have stacked with that.

The goal is to crop image like this:
[image]

Think of every step like it is different html pages (page-1.html, page-2.html, page-3.html).

**In the page-1.html** background is pretty simple. The important think to admit - this pictures have to be responsive.

`page-1.html`

```
background-image: url(image-1.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0;
background-size: cover;
```

The second example can be done by using `<svg>` elements.
`page-2.html`

```
<svg id="bigTriangleColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="triangle-svg">
    <path d="M0 100 L50 0 L100 100 Z"></path>
</svg>

<style>
    .triangle-svg {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        fill: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

But what about third example? I don't know how to deal with it.
In 3 example we see something like:

```
<div class='top-layout'></div>
<div class='bottom-layout'></div>
```

The `.top-layout` image should be croped. The `<svg>` decision is bad because we should able to put second image uderneeth the first.

```
.top-layout {
   height: 500px;
}
.bottom-layout {
   height: 500px;
   position: relative;
   top: -150px;
}
```

And all this stuff should be responsive with `background-size: conver` effect.

Comment: canvas will be the better option

Comment: could you provide an real example?

Comment: It's very broad friend, you have to study clipping images on HTML5 canvas

Comment: SVG will work just fine; you just need to do the work. Use a [clipping path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) on `<image>` elements, and layer them as you like in document order. If you want this as a background, absolutely position (or `position:fixed`) the SVG behind your HTML content, with appropriate dimensions in the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

@phrogz deserve all the credits since he answered first.

Demo of [clip-path, mask and gradient](http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/JwkYm/13/). For your solution, replace the contents of group `<g clip-path="url(#clip-bottom)" > ... </g>` with your own `<image .... clip-path="url(#clip-bottom)" />`. Usually I'd create a `g`roup with `clip-path` to keep the `image` tag cleaner, but that's my own preference.